# Kotlin for Android: OnItemSelected Listener

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an android project with Kotlin

I would like to get values position out of spinner listener.

I try to put a global variable and change it, but it is only changed in the listener but returns the initial value of x

```
var x:Int?=null

class sem1gpaactivity : AppCompatActivity(){

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.sem1gpa)
    val firstterm01 = arrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    val spinner = findViewById<View>(R.id.spinnerfirsttermh1) as Spinner
    val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, firstterm01)
    // The drop down view
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) 
    spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter

    spinner.spinnerfirsttermh1!!.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
      x = p2
      }
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
   }

    gpa1.text= x.toString()

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, and you are making your thing complex. If you want the selected item position from the Spinner. Do it like this.

This is the XML of your Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="395dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in your Code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var x: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val spinnerItems = arrayOf("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6")
        spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerItems)
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                x = position
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The position parameter will tell you about the position. And you do not need to use `findViewById()` when working with Kotlin. So the code is simple and concise.

**The position starts from 0 so you may need to add 1 in the position variable (depending upon your need).**

Hope this helps.

Comment: forgive me you did not understand what i want i want onItemSelected to send the position out of fun and class and save it in variable x and print it on text view

Comment: Dude you have the position.. now you can do whatever you want assign it on a different variable or display it on TextView. If you can toast the value you can also display it in TextView.

Comment: i want to do that but in only available in on itemselected function but i want do it outside  the function it is possible  ??

Comment: Define a class variable and store the value in it when the item os selected.

Comment: Because you have not changed the spinner selection.. and the select listener is never called.. did you change the selection of spinner?

Comment: if i call x inside the fun it changed but when i call it outside it listener it never change

Comment: What do you mean by call outside.. print the value of log inside listener it is changed. Inside the listener you can call another function that will process your variable x. You need to call a function to see the updated value everytime the selection is changed inside the listener.

Comment: i mean i want to send the value of the  position out of listener i want to call fun to see update of x but not inside fun of listener  ?!

Comment: if you have looked at my cod you will see text view** gpa1.text=x.tostring() **it doesnot show the change of x

Comment: Listen when your program loads the value of x is 0. Then you are using it in some function. That function may be also called when your apps load. But this function where you used the value of x is not getting called when the spinner item is changed. Understood?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to put a global variable and change it, but it is only changed in the listener but returns the initial value of x

Put `var x:Int?=null` in the line directly after `class sem1gpaactivity : AppCompatActivity(){` and it should work. Otherwise your variable is not a global variable *in the class.*

You were very close on the right track.